# Explorer.exe keeps crashing if effects are enabled Error Status Code: c0000185

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-explorer, pagefile, desktop-effects

The `explorer.exe` keeps crashing before every minute after starts when all the effects are activated.

These are the details of the error:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   InPageError
  Error Status Code:    c0000185
  Faulting Media Type:  00000003
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: a7aa
  Additional Information 2: a7aa91f17ea749d42a4de3b390fa5b3d
  Additional Information 3: a7aa
  Additional Information 4: a7aa91f17ea749d42a4de3b390fa5b3d

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

I suspect there's a problem with my hard drive ('cause I already have to format/install twice before this error) but not pretty sure why **if I disable all the effect (Performance options) help to stop the issue.**

#### Update 1

I have just installed Service Pack 1 and the problem persists.

#### Update 2

I already uninstalled and installed drivers from HP and the `explorer.exe` crashes just after I enable effects.

#### Update 3

I'm testing every effect, to try figure out, if particular one of them cause the explorer.exe to crash.

- "Use visual styles on windows and buttons"  - Tested and passed (more than 5 minutes with out crash).
- "Enable Aero Peek" - Tested and passed (more than 5 minutes without crash).
- "Smooth edges for screen fonts" Tested and passed (more than 5 minutes without crash).
- "Smooth-scroll  list boxes" Tested and passed (more than 5 minutes without crash).
- "Use drop shadow for icon labels  on the desktop" Tested and passed (more than 5 minutes without crash).
- "Slide open combo box" Tested and passed (more than 5 minutes without crash).
- "Show windows content while dragging" Tested and passed (more than 5 minutes without crash).
- "Shouw translucent selectino rectangle" Tested and passed (more than 5 minutes without crash).
- "Show thumbnails instead of icons" Tested and passed (more than 5 minutes without crash).
- "Show shadows under windows"  Tested and passed (more than 5 minutes without crash).
- "Show shadows under mouse pointer" Tested and passed (more than 5 minutes without crash).

**The problem is back if I choose "Let windows choose what's best for my computer"**

#### Update 4 it seems fixed with this

Well I just delete pagefile (actually, disable/delete pagefile.sys) from "Performance Options window at Advanced tab" ( go to Control Panel->view advanced system settings) and reboot.

**Note if you are not able to open Control Panel:**
Try this one of these:

1. Press WindowsKey+R to open "Run" windows and type: **control sysdm.cpl**

   - Then go to the Advanced Tab and click "Settings" at the Performance Section
2. From the File menu at Task Manager (Ctrl+Alt+Supr) then "New Task (Run)"  and Then go to the Advanced Tab and click "Settings" at the Performance Section

After that:

Also run this command to delete the hiberfil.sys

```
powercfg –h off
```

And turn it on again:

```
powercfg –h on
```

Reference [Delete hiberfil.sys](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-delete-hibernation-file-hiberfil-sys/)

I try this, because of this thread: [In Page Error](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1389222)  not pretty sure if is the solution or why but explorer.exe stop crashing even with all the effects activated, I'll post tomorrow to tell you if the the crashing continues or stop.

But if the problem is the HDD, well I will quote the last message at the forum thread:

> Just rebuild the page file and see if that helps...
>
> Which if the disk is dying is just working around the issue, perhaps for a very short period of time, at which point much of your data may become corrupt.
>
> If you can easily put the HDD in another machine to get a backup, do so. If it comes up clean, that's great, if it doesn't, you have a chance to get a backup of critical stuff and replace the HDD.

#### Update 5 still working

I try some test from the hp utility:

- Start test: Failed
- HDD test: Disk not installed << kind of weird I just boot after that.

And just to mention, after the update 4 the explorer.exe didn't crash anymore.

#### Update 6 running some tests with HDDScan:

- Short self-test: error with read elemetn failed << stops at 10%
- RD-Test still running, but at 100%:

  ```
  < 5ms  3717065
  < 10ms 17621
  < 20ms 29628
  < 50ms 46193
  < 150ms 4775
  < 500ms 157
  > 500ms 48
  Bads 34
  ```

#### Last update:

By the way, after the update 4 (delete pagefile.sys) the problem didn't come back

But everything points to the HDD, probably is "dying" or have some bad sectors just in the "right place".

Some refs:
Here: answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/windows-7-explorer-crash-bug-explorer-has-stopped/06f4ac0c-e486-491e-8861-30903b8791b1

at the link above the error status code is "c000009c" but we share the Fauling Media Type: "00000003".

And here: support.microsoft.com/kb/884070 please add the http...

It saids that both (and others) status error code are pretty much the same or relateds.

> More information for advanced users
>   The following error signature applies to the error message that is mentioned in the "Symptoms" section.
>
> EventTypeName  NTStatusCode
>   InPageError    c000009c or C0000185 or C0000102 or C000003F or 00000002 or 00000003

**Some previous attempts, before posting:**

- I already replace `shell32.dll` and `explorer.exe` using the Windows 7 DVD

  - Reference: youtube.com/watch?v=FT42A6iYWj8

```
Sorry because of the spam restriction for new users I just can use two hyperlinks
```

- Run `chkdsk c: /f`
- Run `sfc`

My regards !

Laptop Model:  ProBook 4520s
Windows Version: Profesional 32 bits.

Comment: Have you tried `chkdsk`? Go to Computer -> Right Click on C: or whatever your main drive is -> select properties -> 'Tools' tab -> Check now... -> check 'scan for and attempt recovery...' -> Start.

Comment: Hi, yes I already perform a "chkdsk c:/f" command and the problem persist, also I already try with the sfc command and didn't work

Comment: ...Is this computer new? Did it just start doing this? How long has this been happening? Did you install any new programs before SP!?

Comment: The computer isn't new, it starts like 9 hours ago.
And not I didn't install any program when starts, yesterday I install Label Matrix and Zebra Designer Pro 2.x,with some zebra drivers, but I've uninstalled both programs and all the printers.

I was debugging with visual studio web developer express 2010 and writing a mail at lotus notes 7.x when suddenly the explorer.exe just crash and keep doing it until I disabled the visual effects (just by luck because run "Microsoft Fix it Center" then this program tell me about run visual options.)

Comment: Right now I'm trying to figure out it if there's some particular effect that cause explorer.exe to crash I jus enable "Use visual styles on windows and buttons" and explorer keeps running.

Comment: @Allende is that the entire problem signature?

Comment: Oamm what do you mean exactly ? Well, I  just clicked at "Show details" at that's all the info I got.

Comment: @Allende I was looking at similar issues, but those problem signatures had a line `Fault Module Name` which pretty much pointed at the faulty software.

Comment: @Louis Ahh ok, thanks, well, it's the whole message just as in this forum thread: [In Page error](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1389222) and after delete pagefile and hiberfil.sys the problem seems go away, but as the last message at the forum thread saids, if the HDD is "dying" (as I'm afraid) probably is just a temporary solution.

Comment: @Louis I'm not sure, but if the explorer.exe or the program/process that is in charge of the effects use/write/read the pagefile.sys and as I'm afraid the HDD is kind of dying, problably it make some of sense that deleting/restoring pagefile.sys it helps

Comment: @Allende Good luck, keep us posted. BTW, if your HD is using S.M.A.R.T. maybe you can [check its health](http://superuser.com/questions/520780/tool-to-test-hdd-for-health).

Comment: Have you done a RAM test?

Comment: c0000185 = STATUS_IO_DEVICE_ERROR Try to change the cables.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe no I didn't, but I'll take your advice if the problem back again tomorrow.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I'll ask for one tomorrow to the support guy, thanks, I'm almost sure the HDD is dying, in the past month I had to give format twice from linux, because Windows Installer (from the dvd of HP) didn't work, and I remember some IO error when test the disk with the partition manager from ubuntu.

Comment: Well, it looks like the HDD is bad, and some lucky (and bad) sector was right at the pagefile.sys and for some reason it was related to the visual effects and to the explorer.exe, the problem goes away, but probably the HDD is damaged (refer to the last update at my post). My regards and thanks to everyone for your time.

Comment: ok. STATUS_IO_DEVICE_ERROR can be broken HDD or broken cables. Replace it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I don't think this is a disk error.

I think it is more likely to be either a component error, either memory or the graphics. Alternatively, it might be the graphics card driver.

Comment: I think that too, well, first I'm installing the SP1 for windows 7 (44mb) to see if the error goes away, after that I'm going to download and install an updated video driver. Let me reboot.

Comment: SP1 didn't help, trying now with last drivers form hp web page: [drivers](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=es&cc=bo&prodNameId=4145202&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=4145198&swLang=35&taskId=135&swEnvOID=4053#11360)

Comment: Reinstall drivers didn't work neither :(

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with my notebook from Dell. I tried a lot of steps to solve it and after three days I got to solve the problem. Probably the problem was really into the hard disk, with my explanation to solve it you will understand:

1) You need another PC, with entry sata cable from HD to motherboard. Of course, you need a power sata cable for HD too. You can note this configuration schema when you open your PC, it will be the same schema but you will have two HD, (HD's from PC and notebook).

2) Before to put the new HD in the PC, to take off all cables from power. After that turn on all cables again and of course the turn on the power again. Turn off the cables it is important to prevent some problem with the power.

3) You can start the windows and the windows will recognize another HD.

4) Find the new HD in D: or F: or ... Then click in the new HD with the right button mouse, properties, tools, checking errors. To select to "auto-correct"

5) The process must be slow, but it is necessary to wait.

6) When all steps to correct it will over. Turn off the computer, repeat the step 2 and to put the HD again in the notebook.

7) You can turn on the notebook and that's all, the windows explorer will work again!

Hope this helps you.

Good Luck!

All the best

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty odd... My theory is that one of the shell addins for explorer are causing the crash. Download Autoruns and try updating programs with addins (such as Adobe Reader or Dropbox) and disabling any unsigned addins one by one until you find the problematic one.

Comment: Hi.Everything points to a problem with my HDD, I suspect of that, because after disable the pagination the problem keeps away, and according to the comments at the links under "Last update",we already had to replace the disk, but I hope the post help someone else at the future.

Comment: Could be... if you suspect drive failure, BACK UP YOUR DATA! Then, download DiskCheckup and see if you have a large number of pending/reallocated/uncorrectable sectors.