# Explorer.exe keeps crashing during log in

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, crash

**Update 2:** `CHKDSK` fix was temporary. It came back again after a while. This time, `CHKDSK` reported more bad sectors. This issue continued untill my HDD crashed completely. Thanks to magicandre1981, I backed up my data.

**Update:** Solved the issue after some trial and error. The file `{AFBF9F1A-8EE8-4C77-AF34-C647E37CA0D9}.1.ver0x0000000000000020.db` in `AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Caches` was corrupt. Scheduled *CHKDSK* could not recover it. Moreover, somehow it corrupted some other files, which prevents the windows from booting. Now I can not access the *good profile* either.

Then I booted from Windows 7 installation disk and choose `Reapir my computer`. I opened command prompt and ran CHKDSK from there:

```
CHKDSK /R /F C:
```

After several (long) hours, file system scan completed. It recovered some corrupted files and reported a few bad sectors. :-( But after I restarted the computer, windows booted normally (faster than before, i think).

---

I have got a weird problem. My windows 7 has two user accounts (both are administrator). I can log in to one account and do all sort of work. But whenever I try to log in to other account, it shows a blank screen and a messagebox pops up with "windows explorer has stopped working".
The options available are:

- Close the program
- Check online for a solution and close the program

The problem signature is as follows:

```
Problem Event Name:     InPageError
Error Status Code:      c000009c
Faulting Media Type:    00000003
OS Version:         6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
Locale ID:          1033
Additional Information 1:   0a9e
Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3:   0a9e
Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

If I press alt+ctrl+del and then select start task manager, it also crashes. I can not run any program using runas command (from good profile) too. The task manager and runas programs all show same problem signature.

I read the similar [question](https://superuser.com/q/521262/331846) and followed all the steps, but no luck.

Later, I viewed the event log and found that, explorer.exe could not access a file. I checked the location but the file is there. The actual message is:

> Windows cannot access the file C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Caches\{AFBF9F1A-8EE8-4C77-AF34-C647E37CA0D9}.1.ver0x0000000000000020.db for one of the following reasons: there is a problem with the network connection, the disk that the file is stored on, or the storage drivers installed on this computer; or the disk is missing. Windows closed the program Windows Explorer because of this error.

The question is, how can I resolve this issue? Should I just delete the file or replace it with another one to stop explorer.exe from crashing?

offtopic:  What is the content of this file and why it is necessary?

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you [start Windows in safe mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7) or [perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us)? What happens if you use `runas` with the `/noprofile` switch? Have you ever used [Tor Browser Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en)?

Comment: @and I tried safe mode and clean boot, but the problem persists. I used Tor before, but never used in this installation.

Comment: This happened to me and a chkdsk fixed it as well. I was on Windows 8.1 x64. Same exact folder on my system, with a similarly named file.

Comment: @IronicMuffin As the accepted answer indicates, it was actually a disk issue. The `CHKDSK` fix was temporary. It came back again and again; every time, # of bad sectors increased and ultimately my HDD crashed totally. It did not even show in BIOS. Hope yours is not that bad. :)

Comment: @asif Thanks for the extra information. I've had some issues with loose SATA cables, which I believe are resolved. I'd like to think it's a one time issue, but good to know - I will prepare myself for further issues just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inpage error and your error code

```
err c000009c
# for hex 0xc000009c / decimal -1073741668
  STATUS_DEVICE_DATA_ERROR                                       ntstatus.h
```

means that Windows is unable to read data from the HDD. So you should backup as many data as possible (using a Live OS like Linux) and run a HDD diagnostic tool from your HDD manufacture to see details.

Answer (score 0):

If one account works and the other doesn't then, from experience, you most probably have some malware that is being loaded when the "broken" account logs in. Run a malware and antivirus scan.

Another solution may be to backup the broken user files, delete and then recreate the user account with a fresh profile.