# Lenovo Y50 Windows 8.1 Files always get corrupted

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, filesystems, lenovo-laptop

I've set a new NTFS partition (X:) on a new Lenovo Y50 laptop, through Windows' (8.1) Disk Management tool.
Just a normal disk partitioning.

The problem is that **files get corrupted constantly**.
What I mean by corrupted is that I try to open a file, which could be of any type (exe, txt, csv etc'), and I get a message that this file is not accessible. Too shame I did not record the error number, and it happened many times already.

The only solution is to use Windows' error check and repair tool (on a partition level) which basically removes these corrupted file.
This is a huge problem, that you never know which files you are going to lose.

So every day I have to do an error check and repair (by clicking on the Properties menu option of the drive, going to the "Tools" tab and then "Check") the drive.
If I don't do that routine for a few days it becomes unbearable - a whole directory is not accessible.

I'm pretty sure I'm losing files without even noticing, but sometimes it does hit important files.

This is crazy!

Again, it happens only on one partition (drive X, not the system one which is C).

How can I fix that situation?
If it was the whole drive then the other partition should have been affected as well.
That is a standard NTFS partition I've made.

Comment: What is your storage drive reporting its health as?

Comment: Your assumption that the whole drive would be affected in the same way is flawed (it could very well not show up while using other partitions).  Test the drive with the manufacturer's utilities, check SMART, etc. and plan to replace the drive. Otherwise to fish for specific help, then provide specifics - the exact errors you're getting, the results of your chkdsk when it repairs this problem, the drive make and model, etc.

Comment: You mean the "Status" column at "Disk Management"? It's "Healthy". Everything is allegedly fine, but..

Comment: See this other SU question regarding testing the drive: http://superuser.com/questions/520780/tool-to-test-hdd-for-health

Comment: Ok downloaded HDDScan, going to check the drive and will report back in a few. Thanks guys! Talk soon

Comment: Ok it didn't detect anything wrong. The "Conveyance", "Short" and "Extended" tests finished without any error. Other reports don't show any error either. Should I run the "Surface" tests? Which? The "Read"?

Comment: Yeah do a Read-only surface test next. The Write version will Most likely) delete all the data on the drive (which may be worth doing; after making a backup).

Comment: I will do so as soon as possible.. I've found a scarier thing now! Some directory with many files that I have here.. Some of the files became 0 bytes. Now, when I delete one of these 0 bytes files, another file (which was just in the right size of a few MBs) becomes 0 bytes! WTF?! Any idea?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Here's the report from the RD-Read scan: http://i60.tinypic.com/2ufytnc.png

Comment: There are many text lines such as "Block start at 711680 time 56ms" from 50ms to 220ms.. What do you think? Is there any test I should be taking? Please, just let me know. Thank!